# Why does modifyNumberUp toggle add/remove and next/previous

Tags: javascript, ide, rstudio, editor, ace-editor

*Note: I actually stumbled across this behavior in [RStudio](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/51009f4cff7b0f45f9bd8762d7c0514b0de537bd/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/ace/AceCommand.java#L158) on MacOS yet I assume it is rather about Java/JS.*

When you place your cursor right after a number you can increment/decrement it via OPTION + SHIFT + ARROW UP/DOWN (or CNTRL + SHIFT + ARROW UP/DOWN for windows. This shortcut probably invokes the keybinding `modifyNumberUp` / `modifyNumberDown`. However, it also toggles the word pairs **add/remove** and **next/previous**.

1. What is going on here? Is it actually JS or something else?
2. Why does this happen? What is the purpose?
3. Is there a list of words that are defined that way?

Just paste the following in a code editor like https://ace.c9.io/, set the cursor, and use the shortcut.

```
1
add
next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found the source of this behaviour. RStudio - and many other editors - refer to the [Ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) editor (which is written in JS).

> RStudio consumes several JavaScript libraries, including Ace (text editor) and xterm.js (terminal emulator)

[RStudio Documentation](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/wiki/GWT-(Google-Web-Toolkit))

Within this editor, there is a [function `modifyNumber` defined](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/cbcb78c3a7c5e642d615a9f5665a44dbb94d3e92/lib/ace/editor.js#L1750). In case the input is not a number, [the function `toggleWord`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/cbcb78c3a7c5e642d615a9f5665a44dbb94d3e92/lib/ace/editor.js#L1820) is triggered. This Function uses a [list of `toggleWordPairs`](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/cbcb78c3a7c5e642d615a9f5665a44dbb94d3e92/lib/ace/editor.js#L1794) to switch between multiple pairs. These are:

```
toggleWordPairs = [
  ["first", "last"],
  ["true", "false"],
  ["yes", "no"],
  ["width", "height"],
  ["top", "bottom"],
  ["right", "left"],
  ["on", "off"],
  ["x", "y"],
  ["get", "set"],
  ["max", "min"],
  ["horizontal", "vertical"],
  ["show", "hide"],
  ["add", "remove"],
  ["up", "down"],
  ["before", "after"],
  ["even", "odd"],
  ["in", "out"],
  ["inside", "outside"],
  ["next", "previous"],
  ["increase", "decrease"],
  ["attach", "detach"],
  ["&&", "||"],
  ["==", "!="]
];
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a similar editor right here and it does not behave the way you have mentioned. RStudio & ace.c9.io might have put this feature separately, and it has nothing to do with JS itself, although they could have coded it in JS. THe reason would be convenience for users who have certain combinations used repeatedly. A better place to look for a list of words would be the docs, or if they have, their forums etc.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. no sources nor any specific reasonings

Comment: What kind of source would you need to prove that something doesn't exist? I am telling you it is NOT standard JavaScript. Try this behavior in the editor you are using to post content on stack overflow, right here. You'd see this editor does NOT behave this way. Every editor behaving this way would have this feature specifically programmed for it, i.e. no standard "list of words" to "rule them all".

Comment: well, isn't it notable that multiple editors share the same functionality? for example, if this is a native RStudio feature, why is there only one reference in some JAVA code yet no definition of a function that would cause this behaviour? Seems to me that they refer to some sort of single source of truth. there must be a function where it is defined that previous/next are coupled like numbers. either in the RStudio source code, where I could not find it, or somewhere else. that would be the source that I am looking for.

Comment: just to add: I would not have liked to be rude, yet answers, regarding this question, without sources are more like opinions

Comment: And since it seems to you, there must be a single source of truth. Even though the some words would be affected with the same functionality in one of the editors and in the other, unaffected. Great, I hope you are right. And if you do find that source of truth, would you be so kind to let me know as well?

Comment: I finally found it